# Weird lines appear in R graph after copying it "as metafile" to Word and exporting it as PDF

Tags: r, ms-word

Journal in which I am submitting a research paper requires that article should be submitted in PDF-format. I am using R for statistics and graphs.

I have used basic formulas to print my graphs. barplot() for bar charts, boxplot() for boxplots and draw.triple.venn in VennDiagram package. I am not using special commands or formulas for device or graphical parameters.

I print my graphs in R and then copied them "as metafile" to produce high quality graphs.

When i attach these graphs in R they appear just fine. However, when I print my work as PDF in Word these lines appear to graphs.

[image]
[image]

Example for the first graph:

```
venn.plot <- draw.triple.venn(45, 34, 32,
14, 5, 11, 3, c(sprintf("Elevated\nWB Cr and Co"), sprintf("Mixed       or\nsolid PT"), sprintf("Moderate to severe\ng.minimus atrophy")),
lwd = 4,
lty = 'solid',
cex = 3.5,
fontface = "bold",
fontfamily = "sans",
cat.cex = 1.8,
cat.fontface = "bold",
cat.default.pos = "outer",
cat.pos = c(-20, 20, 180),
cat.dist = c(0.115, 0.115, 0.095),
cat.fontfamily = "sans",
rotation = 1
);
```

Example for the second:
`boxplot(df$Crmri~df$gmed2,log="y",yaxt="n",ylim=c(0.3,200));
axis(2,at=c(0,1,2,10,20,100),labels=c("0 ppb","1 ppb","2 ppb","10 ppb","20 ppb","100 ppb"),las=2);`

I have several barplots in Word file and after saving as PDF these graphs are just fine.

At first I tried to save those graphs as metafile in R and adding them to Word after but the lines still appear. If I open my EMF-files in any other Viewer those lines are not there.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This is off-topic here: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for advice. But you would well advised on SO to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide the code you used to generate the plots.

Comment: I´ve now provided the codes for the graphs

Comment: How do you convert/print/export it to pdf?

Comment: I use the "Save as PDF or XPS" option in Word

Comment: Added a solution below using the new export package that just came out on CRAN...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been discussed on r-help before. See:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-September/289705.html

Seems to be due to the way Word converts documents to PDFs when you use "Save As" and then choose PDF.

If you have Acrobat (not just the reader), printing the document via the Adobe PDF "printer" should get rid of the lines. Otherwise, you may have to consider switching to another graphics format (e.g., png).

Comment: Thanks for this! I installed a free PDF printer and all EMF files works fine. The issue seems to be in the Word level

Answer (score 1):

There's a new package `export` that just came out on CRAN that allows you to export graphs to Powerpoint or Word in native Office format. From there you can then save as PDF in Office without problems, without any weird lines appearing, see
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/export/index.html and
https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export

E.g.

```
install.packages("export")
library(export)
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, las = 2)
graph2doc(file="plot.docx", width=7, height=5)
graph2ppt(file="plot.pptx", width=7, height=5)
```

Even after saving to PDF within Powerpoint this will give you a perfect quality vector format PDF without any weird lines :

[image]

Other advantage is that the Powerpoint version you get is fully editable vector format, enabling you to make any small required changes in the layout (it also fully supports transparency / alpha channels).

Comment: Hi Tom, instead of posting the same answer over and over please add a link to one of the answers in a comment. Please consider flagging duplicates if you find them.

Comment: Ha yes good idea - I guess I should mark some of these questions as duplicates then right? Problem is that some of them were actually posed as slightly different questions, but that my answer might be relevant for all of them. Probably reflects my enthusiasm after discovering this package the other day :-)

Comment: Tailored my answer to the specific question

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this issue still exists in Word for Office 365 and Word for Office 2016.  Copying from R-Studio as a Metafile results in lines in the plots when you convert to PDF (using Word's Save as PDF function).  Copying from R-Studio as a Bitmap or exporting as an image does not result in lines, but unfortunately the image quality in Word and PDF is not as clear as the Metafile.  The response that described printing the document via the Adobe PDF Printer does avoid the lines, but I found that this approach loses the dynamic links in the text of the Word document (such as Table of Contents links).  I have Adobe Acrobat Pro XI.  So that solution does not work for me.  In the end, the best solution I can find seems to be copying as a Bitmap.  Unfortunately the image quality is not very good.